# Cannot "activate" a venv enviroment for flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

i am having a hard time with python3 and creating a venv for flask.

I have followed the documentation on Flasks website for setting one up but when i do so i get this message:

[image]

Then when i try and activate it this happens:

[image]

I have python3 installed, pip3 and flask installed but can't seem to get this right. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This and let me know if doesn't work

```
pip3 install virtualenv
cd projectfolder 
virtualenv projectname
source projectname/bin/activate
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, after doing the pip3 install virtualenv i also had to install virtualenv and then it activated.